# curl not working on an RHEL8 Server

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, redhat-enterprise-linux, wget, curl

I have 3 running RHEL 8 VM's as Servers connected to my Company's network and for Setup purposes I need to download a script using curl.

The VM's are properly connected to the internet for example I can ping google.com and that works perfectly fine. But if I want to download for example the google page with `curl -v https://google.com/` this happens:

[Network is unreachable error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MyD93.png)

I also checked the Firewall it is not blocking any needed ports. And the NetworkManager is also working perfectly fine.

The I tried to force curl to an ipv4 address with `curl -4v https://google.com/` and after a minute or so I get an Connection timeout error

Similar outcome with ipv6, `curl -6v https://google.com/` throws curl Error 7: Couldn't connect to server (image below)

[curl ipv6 error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D5R6z.png)

Then I tried everything again with **wget** but that also didn't work!

So if anyone has an idea how to fix this problem PLEASE let me now!
Thank you in advance!